# How one can install the font MT Extra on Ubuntu?

Tags: fonts, pdf, okular

I read that my pdf-readers Xpdf and Okular can't show a document from http://math.aalto.fi/opetus/sovtoda/oppikirja/Johdanto.pdf correctly as my Ubuntu or xpdf and evince has not installed the font MT Extra (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=747231). How can I install it?

Comment: @karel Does the geometric mean on page 40 produce the letter L in your version? That should not happen, and that is the whole point of the bug report.

Comment: Yes, the geometric mean on page 40 also produces a capital L in my version.

Comment: After installing MTExtra.ttf, it shows "...", as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a `MTExtra.ttf` file on the Internet, download it and double-click it. Then press the button "Install". Reload the pdf.